# Unix executable corrupts when copied through Java

Tags: java, unix, apache-commons-io

I am trying to copy a *.app file to my Applications folder in OS X, but when I try to do that all Unix executable files gets corrupted and turns into text files.

I have tried the following code using Apache Commons IO:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(FileUtils.getFile(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/JCal.app"), FileUtils.getFile("/Applications/"));
```

And also I have tried using the [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/) code.

Any idea how to get over this problem?

Comment: The example is much the same as the FileUtils does.  If your files are getting corrupt you need to work in what way they are corrupt as the code is not the problem.

Comment: Most of the files you mention are text files already. I assume you mean the images are corrupted. If you mean the text files are you saying you have a special character at the end of each line because you have windows new lines?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thats the problem. I have no idea how thats happening, when I run these codes the Unix file gets converted to a weird text

Comment: What do you mean by weird? So how exactly is it different to the input? What character encoding what used originally?

Comment: Its a Unix file generated by Netbeans when you natively package the code, It gets converted to symbols and question marks. When you double click this Unix file the Jar files execute through terminal.

Comment: Yes thats one way, but if I want to natively pack the files then this is the only way, the app works fine if I move it manually instead of java code. But when I do that with Commons approach the file corrupts.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that commons is corrupting the file. The library is very old and simple. More likely that .app files cannot be read on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

A `.app` file is a Mac OSX specific file format and not portable to other OSes.  Linux has no idea how to read the file and runs it as a script which fails as it is a binary format.

I suggest you build a `.jar` which can be run on any platform.